# Running module is fine in PyCharm, but returns "TypeError" in console

Tags: python, pycharm, typeerror

While running the module through the built-in PyCharm console works fine, running the same module through CMD or Powershell (or CMDER or many other consoles) returns this TypeError:

```
TypeError: get_steady_state() takes from 0 to 4 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

this is the `get_steady_state()` definition:

```
def get_steady_state (wwtp, target_SRT, verbose, diagnose, mn, fDO, DOsat):
...
```

and this is the `get_steady_state` use-case:

```
run.get_steady_state(wwtp, CMAS.SRT, False, False, "BDF", True, 10)
```

In addition: I've already checked the interpreter version, both are python 3.10

I tried to pass all arguments to function parameter as keyword arguments as below:

```
run.get_steady_state(wwtp=wwtp, target_SRT=CMAS.SRT, verbose=False, diagnose=False, mn='BDF', fDO=True, DOsat=10)
```

But I got this `TypeError` instead:

```
get_steady_state() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mn'
```

Comment: What is `run` in your second snippet?

Comment: A possible cause is that you're running the script in a different virtual environment, where a different version of the same package may be installed. Possibly the other version does not expect the same number of arguments.

Comment: @quamrana `run` is a module and `get_steady_state` is one of its functions.

Comment: Is there perhaps another `get_steady_state()` defined somewhere else?

Comment: @quamrana nope! I've searched whole project and just have one `def get_steady_state()`

Comment: @Grismar I actually didn't create a venv at all. Also checked again. There is no .venv folder neither in project directory nor in local pycharm projects directories.

Comment: There must be some reason for the error. Is there some other symbol anywhere called: `get_steady_state`?

Answer (score 0):

After getting the second `TypeError` I made sure there's a `run` module  -and consequently the `get_steady_state` function- somewhere else which PyCharm imports that module while console uses project directory. Then I checked `site-packages` and found an installed module containing the `run` module. So i removed the local `run` file and everything got working.